# How do I get the templars to attack my dens?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have captured every den in the city and one of the assassins challenges is to win three den defences. I noticed this at DNA sequence 3. I am now at DNA sequence 6 and they haven't even attacked one of them. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

In order for the Templars to attack your dens, you have to have your Templar Awareness maxed. Once it hits max, any further attempts to increase your Templar Awareness will provoke an attack on your den. So, if you're maxed out and you kill a guard, they will attack your den. However, they will *not* attack your dens if you have an assassin assigned to it. So, if you've already assigned an assassin to all of your dens, you won't be able to play Den Defense again without replaying the original Den Defense memory.

Comment: If you have assassins in all your dens, you can re-run the memory containing the first den defense to get the three wins required, or the "perfect" win.

Comment: @Rawling Thanks! I didn't realize you could replay that memory.

Comment: This is not exactly right.  They can attack dens with an assassin installed.  It's only dens locked by a MASTER assassin that they can't.  I recommend leaving one den unlocked and provoking attacks because the later den defenses are much more interesting than the one in that memory!

Comment: @Rawling thanks for the answer i didnt know you could realise that you culd do that thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order for for one of your dens to be attacked, your templar awareness needs to be maxed out. If you renovate a shop or get in a fight with guards while the awareness meter is full, it will cause an attack on one of your dens. Note that if a den has a den leader then that particular den will NOT be attacked.

So if you want to start a den defense mission, don't start assigning den leaders to dens just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Attack all the yellow dots at street level that appear on your map. This will raise the Templar's awareness

Answer (score 0):

You need to have max templar awareness red icon on top left corner and just attack guards and never reduce that awareness. If that doesn't work send all your main assassins on mediterranean missions away from their dens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of your dens to be attacked, maximize your notoriety then keep committing mass genocide until your one of your dens gets attacked. If you have Assassins assigned to your den, move them to **Assassin-controlled** cities using the **Mediterranean Defense** option and selecting a city to move them to.

If you somehow manage to build every Assassin Den, liberate ***all*** 14 Mediterranean cities, recruit ***82*** rebellious citizens and train them ***ALL*** to the rank of **Master Assassin**, then you can never play **Den Defense** ever. But, by now once you've played too many rounds to the point where it gets too hard and you get 100% synchronization, it's safe to say no one has done that yet. Hopefully.